# Gatsby Source Contentful 4.x - Rich Text - images and hyperlinks not fetching

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I have a gatsby app for which I am using contentful rich text. contentful recently made some breaking changes to the way content is now fetched and I am quite lost on how to source my links and images from the raw richtext file.

Below is the code I have so far, through which I am fetching the rich text. I see the

tags and s and everything, but when I console log what is brought back to the node for embedded asset blocks and hyperlinks, there is nothing.

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { renderRichText } from 'gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text';

import { BLOCKS, MARKS, INLINES } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';

const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>;
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>;

// Setting the rendering options. Same as:
// https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer
const options = {
    renderMark: {
        [MARKS.BOLD]: (text) => <Bold>{text}</Bold>
    },
    renderNode: {
        [INLINES.ENTRY_HYPERLINK]: ({ data }) => <Link to="/">{console.log(data)}</Link>,
        [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
        [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node) => {
            console.log(node);
        }
    }
};
function privacy({ data }) {
    // console.log(data);

    const description = data.allContentfulBlogPost.nodes[0].bodyRichText;
    return <div>{description && renderRichText(description, options)}</div>;
}

export default privacy;
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query MyQuery {
        allContentfulBlogPost {
            nodes {
                bodyRichText {
                    raw
                    references {
                        ... on ContentfulAsset {
                            # contentful_id is required to resolve the references
                            contentful_id
                            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                                ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

ok, I found the issue. I added the below inside the references and I can now see the assets

```
 ... on ContentfulAsset {
          contentful_id
          __typename
          fixed(width: 1600) {
            width
            height
            src
            srcSet
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for answer for hours...